# paly the videos on single page using iframe from youtube to ionic project

Tags: angularjs, iframe, youtube, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic please help..
I am using iframe to embed the video from youtube to my ionic project,
in my project on every click of new video link, it is opening new view (or page) and previous video is also playing same time. how to fix it.My requirement is at one time only one video should play, on click of other video link on same page this video should play, previous playing video should fade or hide.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by disabling cache on the state where the Youtube video was playing.

try this:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

add `cache: false` to your state.